# How to use a serializer for different fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am working on a project of blog application in Django Rest Framework. But here I am facing some trouble. At first checkout my code then I will explain the question.

Here is the model.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
     id_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
     email = models.EmailField()
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     subject = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     description = models.TextField()
```

And here is the serializer.py

```
class AddContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

> Now in a view function I want to use only email and name field of the Contact model and in another view function I want to use name and description field of that model.
> Can I use the same serializer class for different cases?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple seralizers for a model. Example

```py
class EmailContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['email','name'] # your desired fields here
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use the serializer class for other uses like if I need  [ 'id_no', 'name' ] fields of the model then I have to create a new serializer class.